# The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no longer need to explicitly set it

Tags: ionic, firebase, firestore

Estava praticando fazer aplicativos com Ionic 4 e o Firebase (Cloud Firestore), porém quando eu executo o aplicativo, aparece o erro no console:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.8.1): 
>     The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no
>     longer need to explicitly set it. In a future release, the setting
>     will be removed entirely and so it is recommended that you remove it
>     from your firestore.settings() call now.

Fiz algumas pesquisas (com um inglês bem ruim) vi que podia ser problema com o antivírus Karpersky e/ou ADBlock, já pausei mas continua aparecendo o mesmo erro. Lembrando que fiz a configuração do Firebase de acordo com o tutorial do firestore2.
Segue a print do app.module.ts.

[image: app.module.ts]

Alguém sabe do que se trata esse erro?

PS: Segue algumas informações do package.json
[image: package.json]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade, isso não é um erro, é um alerta ou aviso.
Não está ligado ao antivírus.
A tradução literal seria:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.8.1): A configuração `timestampsInSnapshots` agora é por padrão `true` e você não mais precisa defini-la explicitamente. Em uma versão futura, a configuração será completamente removida, então é recomendável que você a remova da chamada do seu `firestore.settings()`.